# Why is setting alias in .profile not working?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, .profile

I have this as the last line in my .profile:

```
alias gl="cd /home/jrenner/glances/glances"
```

yet even after reboot I get command not found when typing gl. What is happening? I am logged in as the correct user.

Comment: Where are you typing `gl`?  The terminal?  The GUI?

Comment: Nobody ever addressed the original *why?* question. I can confirm that aliases defined in `.profile` do not work in any context I tried: text console logins, graphical terminals, or anything else, even though enviromental variables from the same file do work.

Comment: @DanielMahler, do you have a reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that lpanebr's idea will work, but here's a more elegant solution. Do that alias command in `.bashrc`   That's how I do it, or some people prefer to add a file dedicated to alias.  Call it `.alias` or whatever and add `.alias` to your `.bashrc`

Wish I could do formatting like @lpanelbr. I wonder if there is a wiki?

Comment: As for the formatting askubuntu uses markdown. Please check out http://askubuntu.com/editing-help for the details.

Comment: Why does `.bashrc` work while `.profile` doesn't? Also, any reason why you chose to name the alias file `.allias` rather than `.alias`?

Comment: #1 From what I understand .bashrc is specific to bash and .profile is specific to non-bash command line.
#2 I don't know what you mean. I can spell after all. (edited)

Answer (score 13):

There are two related reasons why aliases don't always work when put in the `.profile` file.  The first is that the `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`) file is only run for a login shell.  If you are starting bash in a terminal window under X, your terminal emulator (e.g. gnome-termanl) probably isn't running bash as a login shell. [Most have an option to change this if you want but the default (for gnome-termal anyway) is not to run it as a login shell.]
The shell will be an interactive shell and so `.bashrc` will be run.

However, normally bash has been run as a login shell back when the X session was being started.  So if there are alias commands in `.profile` they will have been executed along with setting environment variables like the PATH etc. When a terminal window is opened a new instance of bash is run to prompt for, and execute commands in that terminal window.  Unlike environment variables, aliases can not be exported from one instance of bash to a new one started by it.  So the aliases are not passed on to the new shell.

To see this, try this experiment:

```
export ROBERT=bob
alias james=jimmy
echo $ROBERT
alias james
bash               #start a new bash instance
echo $ROBERT
alias james
exit               #end the new bash instance and revert to the original one
echo $ROBERT
alias james
```

Note that `.bashrc` is not run by bash when it is started as a login shell.  So putting your aliases there won't always work unless your `.bashrc` is sourced from your `.profile`, which is a very common practice.

Comment: Verified: adding `source .bashrc` in `.bash_profile` allowed the alias set in .bashrc to work.

Comment: Looks like this should be the correct answer. Also, in Ubuntu just add your aliases in `~/.bash_aliases`. That's the right way to do it. (read the .bashrc file for details).

Answer (score 4):

The right way to do this in Ubuntu is to add your alias to `~/.bash_aliases`. Create the file if it doesn't exist.

This file (if present) is called from the default `~/.bashrc`, and the alias will be available in your terminal emulators too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash (`echo $SHELL`) as a shell interpreter I think it is best (or maybe the only way) if you define your own CD function.

Edit your `.bashrc` file and add the following at the end:

```
# my custom functions:
function gl () {
   cd /home/jrenner/glances/glances/
}
```

You could also extend it like so:

```
# my custom functions:
function cdw () {
   cd /home/jrenner/glances/glances/$1
   ls
}
```

and change directly to a sub directory and list it's contents.

Comment: That may be a fine suggestion, but it is not an answer, as it doesn't explain why the `alias` directive placed in the `.profile` file fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ bash #start a new bash instance
```

This was problem with my server. Simple `source .profile` didn't work for some reason