# Should I put an alias in .bashrc or .profile?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc, alias

I want the following alias to be available each time I open a shell:

```
export ZONE="us-eastern1-c"
export INSTANCE_NAME="myInstance"
alias gc='gcloud compute ssh --zone=$ZONE jupyter@$INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080'
```

Should I put it in `.bashrc` or `.profile`? Also, scanning through `.bashrc` I found:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

So, what's the best practice here? Should I put the alias (**and** the required enviroment variables) in a *third* file, `.bash_aliases`? I'm not a big fan of config file proliferation, but if using this `.bash_aliases` is a best practice, I'll do it.

Comment: The answer is in the observations you posted in your question. Put aliases in .bashrc as the Ubuntu developpers do.

Comment: an alternative would be, to write it into a small script and put it into `/usr/local/bin/`, name it `gc`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ***TL;DR:*** Based on the description you've given, **it can all go in `~/.bashrc`**, even though you would *usually* not want to put environment variables there. There are some other changes you may want to make: exporting the variables is probably unnecessary, and their expansions are best quoted.

As with [Bash aliases in general](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias), you can put your `gc` alias [in `~/.bashrc` or in `~/.bash_aliases`](https://askubuntu.com/a/606882/22949) but it [should *not* go in `.profile`](https://askubuntu.com/a/828105/22949). If the variables are only ever needed in shells where the aliases (which expand to commands that use them) are available, then it is actually fine to put them in the same place as the aliases.

In that case, I'd suggest putting the aliases and variables in `~/.bashrc`, since while it is possible to put *any* commands in `~/.bash_aliases`, it's unusual to put anything other than alias definitions there, and doing so may confuse future readers of your code (perhaps including yourself) and motivate them to wonder if they are looking at a mistake. Of course, you could put the aliases in `~/.bash_aliases` and the associated variables in `~/.bashrc`, but I think that would be much more confusing.

Normally one should not put environment variables in `~/.bashrc`. Most of the time, a user-specific environment variable [should either go](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) in `~/.pam_environment`, which uses its own special syntax, or `~/.profile`, which contains shell commands as `~/.bashrc` does. (See also [these comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile/866240#comment1339715_866240).) One of the reasons for this is that those methods cause the environment variable to be available in most of the situations where it may be needed, which putting it in `~/.bashrc` fails to achieve; one of the reasons for *that* is that `~/.bashrc` is only used by `bash`, and when you log in graphically, that's not `bash`. But when you only need your variables when the aliases that use them are also available, this doesn't apply.

Nonetheless, I suspect that this is actually *not* an exception. But instead of needing to go elsewhere than `.bashrc`, **it looks like those variables don't need to be environment variables**. This is to say that it looks like you don't have to export them, but could instead simply write:

```bash
ZONE="us-eastern1-c"
INSTANCE_NAME="myInstance"
```

This is about the distinction between a *shell variable* and an *environment variable*. In Bourne-style shells like Bash, all environment variables are shell variables, but the only shell variables that are environment variables are those that the shell inherited from its parent process's environment or that have been exported with the `export` builtin.

If programs you run need to inherit `ZONE` and `INSTANCE_NAME` into *their* environments, they you do indeed need to export them as environment variables. And if you need that even in contexts where `~/.bashrc` is not sourced (e.g., running scripts), then it is not sufficient to put those environment variables in `~/.bashrc`.

**Otherwise, they can just be shell variables**, as shown above. The shell will still find them and perform [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on them, in commands generated by expanding the `gc` alias.

---

Whatever you do, I recommend that you modify your alias definition to [double-quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) those variables [when it performs parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F). One way to do that is to define the alias like this:

```bash
alias gc='gcloud compute ssh --zone="$ZONE" "jupyter@$INSTANCE_NAME" -- -L 8080:localhost:8080'
```

Given the their initial values you've shown, that only makes a difference when [`$IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IFS) has an unusual value, since they contain neither whitespace nor any globbing characters like `*`. But it is bad practice to perform unquoted parameter expansion [unless you actually *intend*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) for [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) or [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) to occur.

More importantly, if those variables are reassigned, the new values are used when the command the alias expands to is run. The alias will still expand to the same command (the command it expands to doesn't depend on those variables' values), but the subsequent parameter expansions carried out on `$ZONE` and `$INSTANCE_NAME` will expand them to the new values. Quoting those expansions with double quotes guards against wrong behavior when variables deliberately contain whitespace (or anything in `$IFS`) or any of `*`, `?` and `[`. But you should do it even if you believe or know they should never take on such values, so if they are given such a value by accident, you get comprehensible error messages rather than bizarre and unexpected behavior.

If you don't actually want those variables to exist *at all*, and you are only using them to make the definition of `gc` more self-documenting, then you can define `gc` as a function (in `~/.bashrc`) instead of an alias and make them local variables:

```bash
gc() {
    local ZONE="us-eastern1-c"
    local INSTANCE_NAME="myInstance"
    gcloud compute ssh --zone="$ZONE" "jupyter@$INSTANCE_NAME" -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
}
```